Does a finite non-abelian Group $G$ have a primitive nonabelian quotient $G/N$?
Let $G$ be a finite nonabelian group which is transitive with degree $d$. It is understood that we may construct a primitive group $H = P \wr G$ where $P$ is primitive such that $H/P^d = G$. Now I'm wondering if the opposite is true: Does $G$ have a quotient $G/N$ which is primitive and not abelian?
If not, is there any conditions for $G$ to satisfy in order to have a quotient $G/N$ which is primitive and not abelian?

Note that we require that $N \triangleleft G$ to be proper to begin with.

For example if $G$ is $S_3$ acting regularly on $6$ points. The question is quite unclear to me. For $H$ do you mean the product action? Note that a transitive permutation group always has a primitive quotient acting on a system of  maximal blocks, but there's no guarantee it's nonabelian.

I think that the correct statement is that a finite group $G$ has a non-Abelian homomorphic image which is a primitive permutation group if and only if $G$ is not nilpotent.
For if $G$ is not nilpotent, then $G$ has a maximal subgroup $X$ which is not normal in $G$. Let $N = {\rm core}_{G}(X) < X.$
Then $G/N$ has the corefree maximal subgroup $X/N  = M > 1,$ so that $G/N$ is certainly non-Abelian, but is a primitive permutation group in its action on the cosets of $M$.
On the other hand, if $G$ is a nilpotent finite group, and $N$ is any proper normal subgroup of $G$, then every maximal subgroup of $G/N$ is normal, so that if $G/N$ is a primitive permutation group, then $G/N$ has a corefree maximal subgroup, which must be the trivial group. Hence $G$ can have no non-Abelian homomorphic image which is a primitive permutation group.

In the converse of your proof, you assumed that if $H$ is primitive, then there exists a maximal subgroup which is corefree. May I know where's the source of this fact?

If $H$ is a primitive permutation group, then $H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_{n}$ for some $n$ such that the point stabilizer $H_{1}$ is a maximal subgroup of $H$ with $[H:H_{1}] = n.$  If $H_{1}$ contains a normal subgroup $N$ of $H$, $N$ fixes each point of ${1,2,3, \ldots n},$ so that $N = 1.$ Hence $H_{1}$ is corefree in $H$.

Thanks, I have also found an interesting argument that if $G$ is primitive, then every nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ is normal as well. Moreover if $G$ is nilpotent, then $G \cong C_p$.

I just quoted what I have found in Derek Robinson's Group theory textbook. Yup, it does imply that what you have said earlier is true.
